# Customizing Dictionary Class Override Issue With __getattribute__

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to generate a base class that inherits from `dict`, `object` and another class called `base`.

The class `base` just contains a bunch of web functions that almost all classes in the library will inherit from.

The functionality I want is as follows:

```
 d = BaseService()
 print d.a
```

If the attribute `a` does not exist, I want it to call a function and try to get the value. If the function cannot find the value, I want the standard error to be raised:

```
 AttributeError: 'BaseService' object has no attribute 'a'
```

I went ahead and implemented the code as follows:
    class base(object):
        def _get(url, param_dict=None, securityHandler=None):
            param_dict = {'f': "json"}
            url_values = urllib.urlencode(param_dict)
            full_url = url + "?" + url_values
            res = urllib2.urlopen(url=full_url)
            return json.loads(res.read())

```
class BaseService(dict, base):
    _url = None
    _securityHandler = None
    _proxy_url = None
    _proxy_port = None
    def __init__(self,
                 url,
                 securityHandler=None,
                 initialize=False,
                 *args, **kwargs):
        self._url = url
        self.update(*args, **kwargs)
        super(BaseService, self).__init__()
        self.__init()
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self.__dict__[name] = value
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init(self):
        """
        private function that loads the service properties into the class
        """
        res = self._get(url=self._url,
                        param_dict={"f":"json"})
        self.update(*(), **res)
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if hasattr(self, key) == False:
            return None
        val = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        return val
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, val)
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __str__(self):# NOT WORKING AS EXPECTED
        return json.dumps(self)
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name not in self.__dict__:
            self.__init()
        return self.__getattribute__(name)
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __repr__(self):
        dictrepr = dict.__repr__(self)
        return '%s(%s)' % (type(self).__name__, dictrepr)
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for k, v in dict(*args, **kwargs).iteritems():
            self[k] = v
```

I tried implementing the following:

```
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        d = BaseService(url="https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest)
        print str(d)
        # prints '{"currentVersion":"4.1"}'
        print d.currentVersion
        # raises an error where __getitem__ isn't being called.
```

but this gives me some circular calls, which is not good.

Comment: Why do you need this at all? If you inherit from `base`, then all of its attributes are already accessible within `BaseService`. If you end up in `__getattr__` then why check `hasattr` (and why the explicit comparison to `False` rather than `if not ...`)?

Comment: When the function __init() is called, it reached out to a REST service and loads the information back into the class as a property.  If the value 'a' in my example does not exist, it firsts sees if the REST service has the property, then I need it to fail.

Comment: But you've already done that in `__init__` - are you expecting that the response and therefore attributes will change over time? [Sidenote: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ ]

Comment: Correct, attributes can change over time depending on the actions done on the web service.  These are dynamic services, and the operations performed on them can effect the properties.

Comment: I see; I think your only problem here is calling `hasattr`, which is redundant - if you're in `__getattr__`, then `self` doesn't have that attribute.

Comment: oh ok, so can I just do a "a" in self.__dict__? in the GetAttribute

Comment: No, why would you bother? If it was, it would *already have been resolved*. All you need to do is call `__init` and then try to access the attribute again.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - where would I call self.__init() again to do the re-check?  To improve performance, shouldn't I only make calls if the item does not exist?

Comment: Yes... but, again, **if you're in `__getattr__` it does not exist**. [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) - *"Called when an attribute lookup has not found the attribute in the usual places..."*. It is `__getattribute__` that is called either way.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it appears overriding the __getattribute__ seems to mess up my implementation of allowing my to do <object>.variable.  Any suggestion?

Comment: Please [edit] the question with a [mcve], not just *"seems to mess up"*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added a full sample.  It appears the __getattribute__ is being called when <object>.<variable> is being used, then __getitem__ is never called.  Any idea why?

Comment: `__getattribute__` is called when you do `X.var` and normally **it will call `__getattr__`** if the value is not found in the instance attribute dictionary or class definition etc. it is also responsible for handling bound methods and the like.  The point is that if `__getattr__` is called at all then it means that the attribute was not found.

Comment: `x.var` calls `__getattribute__` which can't find it so it calls `__getattr__` which updates then call `__getattribute__` which still didn't find it so it calls `__getattr__` which updates then calls `__getattribute__`.... does this clear up the flow of execution?